# Environment with a dummy parameter

Tags: environments

This couple of commands

```
\def\look{\@ifnextchar[{\@lookY}{\par\noindent{\textsf{ThinkOut. }}}}
\def\@lookY[#1]{\par\noindent\textsf{ThinkOut (\textit{#1}).}}
```

provides a utility with an effect

```
\look Deep thought ...
```

gives

> ThinkOut. Deep thought ...

and

`\look[addition] Deep thought` ...

gives

> ThinkOut (addition). Deep thought ...

I would like to organize the commands above into an environment but without usage of `amsmath.sty` + `ntheorem.sty` utilities. This is because usage of the scheme

```
\newtheoremstyle{Rstyle}{}{}{\itshape}{2em}{\sffamily}{.}{}{}
\theoremstyle{Rstyle}
\newtheorem{rem}{ThinkOut}
\newtheorem*{rem*}{ThinkOut}
```

does not allow me to emphasize the `[addition]` dummy argument in
`\begin{rem}[addition] ... \end{rem}` independently of the title "ThinkOut". Is it possible to solve the problem by means of the ams-internal utilities above or needs to create my own command? Formatting the `[addition]` argument (if it has been called) is described in the second of commands above `\@lookY`.

Comment: I don't understand actually. Do you want to have a theorem like environment which accepts `[addition]`?

Comment: Yes, this is a theorem like environment but with an independent  possibility to format its [addition] argument when it has been typed.

Comment: Should be possible with a wrapper environment, please add a compilable document such that we don't have to glue all together!

Comment: You should take a look at the `thmtools` package, which cooperates with `ntheorem` as well as `amsthm`. It has a `notefont` key, and makes it easy to define new theorem styles.

Comment: Apart from `notefont` key I might have some parenthesises or something other inside/arround the `[addition]`. It seems to me that one to create a simple and new command would be easier. No ...?

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of what can be done with `thmtools`. If you want an easy independent formatting of the optional argument, you have to use `amsthm`, as all keys for the optional argument (`notefont`, &c.) do not work with `ntheorem` (you can define a new `ntheorem style`, but it's not so easy as with `thmtools`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
headfont=\bfseries,%
notefont=\itshape\mdseries\color{red},
notebraces = {\textup{(}}{\textup{)}},
bodyfont = \mdseries, %
headpunct={.\,—\,}, %
spaceabove=\topsep, %
    spacebelow=\topsep]{Rstyle}

\declaretheorem[name=ThinkOut, numbered=no,style=Rstyle]{look}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{look}
   Deep thought.
 \end{look}

 \begin{look}[addition]
   Deeper thought.
 \end{look}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A version using LaTeX theorem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{lookthm}{ThinkOut}
\newenvironment{look}[1][\empty]{\begin{lookthm}%
    \ifx#1\empty\else\textit{(#1)}\fi%
  }{\end{lookthm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{look}
  Deep thought ...
\end{look}
\begin{look}[addition]
  Deep thought ...
\end{look}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly use `amsthm`; the only problem is using the right specification for the header.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{Rstyle}
  {}
  {}
  {\itshape}
  {2em}
  {\sffamily}
  {.}
  { }
  {\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2}\@ifnotempty{#3}{ (\textsl{#3})}}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{Rstyle}
\newtheorem{rem}{ThinkOut}
\newtheorem*{rem*}{ThinkOut}

\begin{document}

\begin{rem}
Some text.
\end{rem}

\begin{rem}[addition]
Some text.
\end{rem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't need numbering and referencing, you can define an environment with an optional argument using plain LaTeX.

```
\newenvironment{thinkout}[1][]%
  {\begin{trivlist}
   \item[]%
   {\bfseries ThinkOut%
   \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else\ (#1)\fi
   .}\quad
  }%
  {\end{trivlist}}
```

To be used as

```
\begin{thinkout} ... \end{thinkout}
\begin{thinkout}[optional addendum] ... \end{thinkout}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{thinkout}[1][]%
  {\begin{trivlist}
   \item[]%
   {\bfseries ThinkOut%
   \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else\ (#1)\fi
   .}\quad
  }%
  {\end{trivlist}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{thinkout}
  Deep thought \dots
\end{thinkout}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{thinkout}[addition]
  Deep thought \dots
\end{thinkout}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wrong. It should be `\ifx\empty#1`. But it's better to leave empty the default argument and make the test to be `\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax`.

Comment: @egreg Right. It now is `\ifx\empty#1`.

Comment: Add also `\relax` after `#1`, one never knows…

Comment: @egreg I changed it now to the detokenize version, to promote the more robust test for emptiness, though it is more cryptic.

Comment: Thanks. Waiting for a `\begin{list}...` version because there is no possibility to adjust vertical spaces before/after/left/right text in the `\begin{trivlist}...` version.