# A double-symbol default argument in environment. Is this a known bug?

Tags: environments

A question inspired by @gernot's elegant answer in the topic
[Environment with a dummy parameter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353624/environment-with-a-dummy-parameter).

However some further experiments lead to the following. Indeed, what the
devil? Take a @gernot version of the `look`-environment there and look at this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newenvironment{look}[1][\empty]%
{\begin{trivlist}\item[]\textsc{ThinkOut}% 
\ifx#1\empty\else\ (#1)\fi.\itshape}{\end{trivlist}}

\begin{verbatim}
\begin{look}[some addendum]
Text ...
\end{look}
\end{verbatim}
\begin{look}[some addendum]
Text ...
\end{look}

\begin{verbatim}
\begin{look}[q]
Seems allright? Look below ...
\end{look}
\end{verbatim}
\begin{look}[q]
Seems allright? Look below ...
\end{look}

\begin{verbatim}
\begin{look}[qq]
Double-q disappears. Where parentheses?
\end{look}
\end{verbatim}
\begin{look}[qq]
Double-q disappears. Where parentheses?
\end{look}

\begin{verbatim}
\begin{look}[aaa]
One of three a's survives; no ()'s do.
\end{look}
\end{verbatim}
\begin{look}[aaa]
One of three a's survives; no ()'s do.
\end{look}

\begin{verbatim}
\begin{look}[ qq]
Allright again.
\end{look}
\end{verbatim}
\begin{look}[ qq]
Allright again.
\end{look}

\begin{verbatim}
\begin{look}[{}aa]
Allright too.
\end{look}
\end{verbatim}
\begin{look}[{}aa]
Allright too.
\end{look}

\begin{verbatim}
\begin{look}[==]
Any double symbol disappears.
\end{look}
\end{verbatim}
\begin{look}[==]
Any double symbol disappears.
\end{look}

\end{document}
```

Or may be this is the known LaTeX bug?

PS. Sorry, I was not able to download the pdf-result file here.

PPS. The system I have is (info from a log-file)

`e-TeX, Version 3.141592-2.1 (MiKTeX 2.3) (preloaded format=latex 2000.11.28)`

`LaTeX2e <2001/06/01> Document Class: article 2001/04/21 v1.4e`

`Standard LaTeX document class`

Comment: With `\begin{look}[qq]` the `\ifx` test is `\ifx qq\empty` and obviously evaluates to true. What did you expect? Use `\ifx\empty#1` instead.

Comment: Sorry for the typo/mistake, it has to read `\empty#1` instead of `#1\empty`.

Answer (score 3):

No bug at all: with `\begin{look}[qq]` the test is

```
\ifx qq\empty
```

which ***obviously*** evaluates true.

The test should be

```
\ifx\empty#1\relax
```

but I'd prefer

```
\newenvironment{look}[1][]
  {%
   \begin{trivlist}
   \item\relax\textsc{ThinkOut}% 
   \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
   \else
     \ (#1)%
   \fi.
   \itshape
  }
  {\end{trivlist}}
```

---

What happens with *your* version and `\begin{look}[ab]`?

The code does

```
\ifx ab\empty\else\ (ab)\fi
```

Since the test evaluates false, the false branch is followed. If you do `\begin{look}[abcdefg]`, the test is

```
\ifx abcdefg\empty\else\ (abcdefg)\fi
```

and the tokens from `c` to `\empty` disappear as part of the true branch. If you try `\begin{look}[aabbcc]`, the test is

```
\ifx aabbcc\empty\else\ (aabbcc)\fi
```

and you get `bbcc` *printed*.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand why `\begin{look}[ab] ... \end{look}` works but `\begin{look}[aa] ... \end{look}` does not? So, only the very first twice-repeated symbol disappears.

Comment: @maximav Follow the conditionals. I added some examples.

Comment: @maximav with `[aa]` the `ifx` compares a and a which is true, with `[ab]` the `\ifx` compares a with b which is false.

Comment: `[ab]` works fine for me under the old version.

Comment: @maximav that did not do `\ifx#1` did it?

Comment: I fixed a missing `}` after `\itshape` in @egreg's solution above but the system replies `Incomplete \if`.

Comment: @maximav the `}` was missing after `#1` (I fixed it above)

Comment: Seems it became work nicely!

Comment: I attempted to modify the updated version `\look` to usage `\begin{list}` instead of `\begin{trivlist}`. So I've changed `\ifx#1\empty` into `\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax`. Not work now unfortunately. An excessive empty parentheses in ThinkOut () I get when `\begin{look} ...` is called. What solution?

Comment: @maximav The syntax of `list` is quite different from `trivlist`